# How to get the same line items from an HTML table on the same line in Python when extrating to CSV file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Python and am trying to extract a table from a website where the items that are on the same line in the HTML table are on the same line in the CSV output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests
URL = 'https://ir.huntsman.com/news-releases/detail/427/huntsman-announces-full-year-2019- 
earnings-another-year-of'
content = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

body = soup.find(text="Table 3 -- Factors Impacting. 
SalesRevenue").find_parent(class_="prntblns")

rows = body.find_all('tr') # Extract and return first occurrence of tr


import csv

for elem in rows:
    wrappers = elem.find_all(class_="prnews_p")
    for x in wrappers:
        title = x.get_text()
        with open("new.csv", "a") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([title])
```

The output gives me something like the below: I would like it so the output is more similar to the table i.e "Polyurethanes (11%) (1%) 5% 4%" are all on one line. I appreciate your help!

```
Polyurethanes
(11%)
(1%)
5%
4%
```

Comment: do you want to extract the full table ?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I don't need to extract the full table, I just need help with the output, currently, it's showing up on different lines, however I would like it on the same line, ideally separated by a comma.

Comment: @jackbauer i meant, do you want the output like that ? [check](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9d3491b6ca6d183f392ef991f7604fbb/result.csv)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://ir.huntsman.com/news-releases/detail/427/huntsman-announces-full-year-2019-earnings-another-year-of")[5][6:18]

df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

Output: [check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9d3491b6ca6d183f392ef991f7604fbb/result.csv)

Update Per user request:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://ir.huntsman.com/news-releases/detail/427/huntsman-announces-full-year-2019-earnings-another-year-of", match="Table 3 -- Factors Impacting Sales Revenue")[0][6:18]

df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks...Can you explain to me what the [5][6:18] mean?

Comment: @jackbauer `pandas` is returning a list of tables. so we have access `list[5]` or `table# 5` and then we have access lists from `[6:18]`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I plan on doing this quarterly so the table # might change, is there a way to search for a string "i.e Table 3 -- Factors Impacting Sales Revenu" and have it give me the table # that the text is located in? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a list with a single `title` element to `writerow` so it's unsurprising that each record is in a separate row.

You can also move opening the file to the outer scope:

```
with open("new.csv", "a") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in rows:
        wrappers = row.find_all(class_="prnews_p")
        writer.writerow(map(lambda x: x.get_text(), wrappers))
```